# Getting the header names of rows matching string

Tags: awk, grep

I'm quite new to Shell Scripting. Right now I'm trying to figure out a shell script code that would allow me to read through all the rows of a .csv file and get only the column header for each row.

For each row, an 'X' is marked on certain columns (to represent that the Name was present for that row). I want to develop a script where upon giving the name of the first row (eg. 'row1'), the output will give me the corresponding name of the header of columns that had 'X' marked. This is a CSV file so columns that are not marked with 'X' are just blanks with the ; delimiter.

Input

```
Index,Name1,Name2,Name3,Name4
row1,X,,X       
row2,,,X,              
row3,X,X,X,
```

If I search for 'row1', the output would be

Output

```
row1  Name1 Name3
```

If I search for 'row3', the output would be

```
row3   Name1  Name2  Name3
```

I'd like the output to be tab delimited but if that's not possible then comma delimited would be fine too.
I'm trying to do this by first using grep on the name of the rows and then piping the output. However, I'm not sure how to formulate a script that would print out the name of the header if an 'X' is marked. I've an idea of using something along that lines of `grep -w 'row1'` and `awk -F , 'NR==1 { for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) if ($i=="X") { n=i;print $n }}'` but I'm not sure how to string it together.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @pLumo Just made the changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the header into an array, and use them from there, e.g.:

*getpattern.awk*

```c
BEGIN { FS="," }

NR==1 { split($0, colhead); next }

$1 ~ pat {
  printf "%s", $1
  for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
    if ($i ~ /X/)
      printf "\t%s", colhead[i]
  }
  print ""
}
```

Run it like this, e.g.:

```
awk -f getpattern.awk pat='row1|row3' infile.csv
```

Output:

```
row1    Name1   Name3
row3    Name1   Name2   Name3
```

Comment: Note that if there are many rows, `row1|row3` might also match `row11` and `row308`.

Comment: @they: in that case limit the pattern with anchors, e.g.: `^(row1|row3)$`

Comment: This works perfectly! Could you explain how the line of code works? Right now I'm trying to modify the code: there are two Indexes `Index 1` and `Index 2`, and searching either indexes would print both indexes, along with the corresponding header names like this `row1(index1)  row1(index2)  Name1 Name3`.

Comment: @omphanik: You should probably post this as a new question. Remember to include example input-/output-data and your current progress

Answer (score 1):

I would use a dedicated `csv` parser, e.g. `python's` `csv` module would do:

```py
import csv
with open('file.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row["Index"], *[item[0] for item in row.items() if item[1] == "X"], sep=" ")
```

Output:

```
row1 Name1 Name3
row2 Name3
row3 Name1 Name2 Name3
```